# What is easier to compose? A german or an english rapsong?

Tags: difference, lyrics

I have to write a rapsong for my graduation work. My mother language is Swiss German, but I'm fluent in English. Now I have to decide, wheter I want to write the song in German or in English.

What is easier and why?

---

Ich muss für meine Abschlussarbeit einen Rapsong schreiben. Meine Muttersprache ist Schweizerdeutsch, aber ich spreche fliessend Englisch. Nun muss ich entscheiden ob ich den Song in Deutsch oder Englisch schreiben möchte.

Was ist einfacher und wieso?

Comment: why downvoting?? its a nice question!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es hängt davon ab, was du willst. Geht es dir um Wortspiele, coole Reime und sprichst du wirklich fließend englisch, ist es einfacher auf englisch. Mein Paradebeispiel ist das Wort "lazy" - selbst für mich, als vielleicht gut sprechender, brauche ich lange um kein Wort mehr zu finden, das sich darauf reimt.

Das "Problem" im Deutschen ist, dass es unglaublich viele zusammengesetzte Worte gibt. Somit gibt es im englischen viel mehr kurze Worte, was sowohl für den Takt/Flow/Rhytmus als auch für das Finden von Reimen leichter ist.

Andererseits ist es ein riesiges Erfolgserlebnis, wenn man z.B. auf das Wort Benutzeroberfläche einen Reim findet - das fühlt sich absolut großartig an ;) dafür kannst du eben mit user interface die Worte user und interface in den folgenden Zeilen verwenden, semantisch umdrehen, spielen - und es ist deutlich naheliegender als auf deutsch, wo der weg von der Benutzeroberfläche zum obeflächlichen Benutzer vielleicht nett, aber eben nicht sonderlich nahe liegend ist ;)

Dafür ist es im Deutschen (gerade als Muttersprachler) einfacher komplizierten Inhalt in Rapform auszudrücken..

BTW: Was für eine coole Aufgabe ist das denn??

Comment: Ich bin in einer Berufslehre (Informatiker) und mache dazu die Berufsmaturität (BM). Diese BM verlangt eine Abschlussarbeit (IDPA - Interdisziplinäre Projekt Arbeit) bei welcher man in Zweiergruppen zwei Fächer zusammenführt und eine Projektarbeit schreibt. Unsere Projektarbeit beinhaltet das komponieren und vermarkten eines Rapsongs. Dabei werden entweder Deutsch und Wirtschaft oder Englisch und Wirtschaft zusammengeführt. Mit deiner Erklärung denke ich ist Englisch einfacher, da ich dieser Sprache aufgewachsen bin. Wir haben uns auch schon überlegt, ob wir ein Hybrid schreiben möchten.

Comment: Welcher Englisch und Deutsch vermischt. Dies wäre interessant für unsere Projektarbeit und bringt Schreibstoff. Die Spits sind meiner Meinung nach (und falls ich dich richtig verstanden habe, auch deiner Meinung nach) einfacher, da wie gesagt zusammengesetzte Wörter einfacher sind zu teilen und wieder zusammenzufügen.

Comment: Hast du Erfahrung im Songschreiben?

Comment: Voll gut!! Ich habe in Deutschland gelernt (witzigerweise das gleiche) und ein solches Projekt ist ein feuchter Traum geblieben ;)

Comment: Die Idee mit dem Hybrid ist gut! Erst Recht wenn es schwer fällt ein Thema zu definieren.. Das Aufwachsen in Zweisprachigkeit, der Wechsel zwischen zwei Sprachen - auch die Vermischung aus Deutsch und Englisch mit zahlreichen übernommenen Worten bietet Stoff ohne Ende.. Spitten ist einfacher, ja. Und ich habe Erfahrung. Allerdings nur auf Deutsch...

Comment: Kann ich dich irgendwie Kontaktieren, FB oder so? Du kannst mir eine Anfrage senden, falls du dabei bist.

Comment: Da http://www.rhino-it.ch/#references?

Comment: Jap kannst du..